# Кнопка нажимается только один раз

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я столкнулся с этой проблемой впервые, не могу найти конкретного решения.

Вот код:

```js
var bet;
var endGame;
var i;
var startGame;

function getRandomFloat(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function error(number) {
  switch (number) {
    case 1:
      $("#result").text("Укажите сумму ставки.");
      break;
    case 2:
      $("#result").text("Вы проиграли " + bet + "$");
      break;
    case 3:
      $("#result").text("Вы поставили " + bet + "$! Желаем удачи!");
      break;
    case 4:
      $("#result").text("Вы выиграли " + (bet * i).toFixed(0) + "$.");
      break;
    case 5:
      $("#result").text("Игра уже идет!");
      break;

  }
}


function bet() {
  if ($("#betInput").val()) {
    bet = $("#betInput").val();
    game();
    error(3);
  } else {
    error(1);
  }
}


function game() {
  i = 1.0;
  endGame = getRandomFloat(1.0, 2.0);
  endGame.toFixed(1);
  startGame = setInterval(function() {

    if (i < endGame) {
      i = i + 0.1;

      $("#count").text(i.toFixed(1));
    } else {

      $("#count").text("1.0");
      clearInterval(startGame);
      error(2);
      i = 1.0;
      endGame = undefined;
      startGame = undefined;

    }

  }, 500)
}



function take() {

  if (i < endGame) {
    //Забрал лавэ.
    $("#count").text("1.0");
    clearInterval(startGame);
    error(4);
    i = 1.0;
    endGame = undefined;
    startGame = undefined;

  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="betInput" type="text" />
<button class="button" onclick="bet()">Поставить</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="count"></div>
```

Так вот эта кнопка отрабатывает лишь один раз, при повторном нажатии ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: bet is not a function
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:24)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: у Вас одинаково называются переменная bet и функция bet

Comment: Т.е. грубо говоря у Вас есть переменная bet, которая хранит функцию, а внутри функции вы значение этой переменной перетираете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var bet;

bet = $("#betInput").val();
```

В этих строках ошибка. Сначала ты создаёшь переменную bet, потом создаёшь функцию bet, то есть в переменную скорей всего будет эта функция, а внутри функции ты присваиваешь значение в эту переменную, тем самым затираешь функцию, замени bet на что-то другое, должно заработать